# Is there a way to offload EclipseLink Cache in Glassfish for EJB to Redis or another outside server for load balancing?

Tags: java, caching, redis, glassfish, eclipselink

I have an EJB packaged in an EAR and deployed to Glassfish.

Currently we just use Glassfish/Eclipselink for caching.

But our server is starting to come under heavy loads and I want to set it up behind a load balancer on AWS.

The problem is, I don't want my cache to be out of sync for automatically spun up instances. I want the instances to be completely automatic.

I know you can set Glassfish up in a cluster, but as far as I know that isn't automatic. I would have to manage it myself. I want to fully automate everything.

It would be awesome if the Glassfish instances could be completely independent of each other, and I could use Redis or another server like that to offload the cache. That way the cache would be in one place, the Glassfish instances could spin up and down automatically and it would never matter, I wouldn't have to register them with a Glassfish cluster. I could also use the same Redis cache for the front end of the application. Glassfish is running the business layer accessible by API calls. The front end web is running separately. I was going to set up a Redis cache for that also, but if they could both share the same cache, that would be awesome.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer on basis of a conceptual level, since I don't know the used products in detail.

Regardless if you add another level of caching, you need to care about the data consistency within your application.

In a cluster setup, a local non-distributed cache is no problem. The  consistancy coordination solves this, e.g. via JMS. You need to explore how to setup the consistancy coordination across your cluster.